# How to systematically export and re-import a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can i systematically export and re-import the same table from a data extension.

currently we have a defect that is fixed by exporting and importing a data extension.

is there any way to systematically do this as a workaround?

Thanks
-Tim Willis

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible but you need to [enable a specific file transfer type through your account executive](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230276&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) first.

Then you create an automation with the following steps:

1. Data Extension Extract
2. File transfer from safehouse to export folder
3. Move or Copy File Transfer (the one you need to activate)
4. Import to your data extension

Due to the wild card limitations your automation should be set to daily or a longer interval as you will run into issues with your files otherwise.

**Important note**
It might be possible to import your extracted file directly from the safehouse, which would reduce the automation to steps 1 and 4. You should try that first to avoid the hassle of getting the activity type enabled.

I haven't tried that, however. Possibly someone from the community can confirm if this works